# Only the bee-line is shown on the map ! why?

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, routes

This is my Code what should show me the route between two points.

```
        RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
        roadManager.addRequestOption("routeType=bicycle");
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        waypoints.add(gp);
        waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(48.92608,9.13641 )); //end point
        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();

        Drawable nodeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_node);
        for (int i=0; i<road.mNodes.size(); i++){
                RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
                Marker nodeMarker = new Marker(mapView);
                nodeMarker.setPosition(node.mLocation);
                nodeMarker.setIcon(nodeIcon);
                nodeMarker.setTitle("Step "+i);
                mapView.getOverlays().add(nodeMarker);
                nodeMarker.setSnippet(node.mInstructions);
                nodeMarker.setSubDescription(Road.getLengthDurationText(node.mLength, node.mDuration));
                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_continue);
                nodeMarker.setImage(icon);                  
                }
```

but this one shows me only the bee-line(airline).
Why I can't see the the normal route for the carway ?